# Sitecore: Foundation Project - Views Folder is not getting deployed during solution rebuild

Tags: helix, deployment, sitecore-mvc

During local solution rebuild or in Dev/QA deployments, one of my **Foundation project's Views folder is not getting deployed** to the webroot.

> **Note:**
>
> - All the views folder from all the feature projects are getting deployed as expected.
> - None of the other foundation projects has views folder.

**Version details:**
Sitecore 10.1.2
Visual Studio 2019

Am I missing anything here?
Or, as per community blogs I see that the publishOptions has to be modified.

Can someone help me how do it allow my foundation views to be deployed.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are the views each marked as Content in visual studio? This can be seen on the properties tab.

Comment: are you using gulp to publish all your projects?

Comment: Yes, it is marked as Content. There was some reference path issue and while I corrected the path, the issue got resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check a few things. Go to `Visual Studio` and right-click on view and select the `properties` tab.

1. Make sure the `Build Action` option for View is `Content` like in the below image.
2. Also `Copy to Output Directory`  has 3 options, make sure to choose as per requirement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav for sharing details. Issue got resolved.

Initially the project was placed in a location as -> /code/<foldername>/projectname.csproj.
Later I moved it directly under /code/projectname.csproj

The reference changes did not happen accodingly in my master project and the view files weren't getting deployed.

Once the path was corrected, things worked as expected.